# $H^1_I(R) \cong S/R$ as $R$-modules.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

> Let $R$ be a domain with quotient field $K$, let $I\neq 0$ be an $R$-ideal, and write $I^{-i}=R\underset{K}{:} I^i$. Then $S=\bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} I^{-i}$ is a subring of $K$ containing $R$. Show $$H^1_I(R) \cong S/R$$ as $R$-modules.

**Proof:** Let 
$$0\to R\to K \to K/R\to 0$$ 
be an exact sequence. Apply $-\underset{K}{:} I^i$ to the sequence
$$0\to R\underset{K}{:} I^i\to K\underset{K}{:} I^i \to K/R\underset{K}{:} I^i\to 0$$
which remains exact. Then
$$0\to I^{-i}\to I^i \to K/R\underset{K}{:} I^i\to 0$$
Apply $\bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} -$
$$0\to \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} I^{-i}\to \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} I^i \to \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} K/R\underset{K}{:} I^i\to 0$$

So far am I correct? If so, what I need to get next is a long exact sequence. I am thinking of using the Tor Functor but I am not sure what the second entry would be?

Comment: I wonder what could mean $K/R\underset{K}{:} I^i$?

Comment: Could you use the `local-cohomology` tag for such questions?

Comment: Well $K/R \underset{K}{:} I^i = \{ x\in K | I^i x \subset K/R\}$. I am not sure how to "simplify" it

Comment: Well, then what could mean $ax\in K/R$ for $a\in I^i$ and $x\in K$?

Comment: Would it be $I^i/R$?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find any meaning to $K/R \underset{K}{:} I^i$.

Comment: I also can't understand how you can miss the wrong conclusions you get by using an erroneous reasoning. How could $I^{-1}$ be contained in $I$???